# Joining two tables in MySQL with one having multiple values in the other table

Tags: php, mysql

Tools table:

```
id      tool_nr   
687      2902
745      2456
234      3245
```

Product Table:

```
id      tool_id   something
3432     687       123456
4587     745       254786
4411     687       258956 
4741     234       874455 
8745     745       987445
```

So, tools table id equals product table tool_id.

What I would like:

```
tool_nr     something
2902        123456
2456        254786
2902        258956
3245        874455
2456        987445
```

As you can see tools table id may have multiple values in the product table, right know my query is giving me "something" values together separated with commas, but I need to change it and I would like to know what would be the best way to do it?

Comment: $sql_string2="SELECT t.tool_nr, p.blabla_nr, p.something  
FROM tools t 
RIGHT JOIN products p ON p.tool_id = t.id AND t.status IN ('Blala', 'Blala') 
WHERE t.id = '".$row["id"]."'       
GROUP BY p.tool_id 
ORDER BY p.blabla_nr DESC";

Comment: SHow your query and how do you want the output to look like?

Comment: I added the query and the output is ^^ there "What I would like".

Comment: Use `left join` instead of `right join`

Comment: That did not work, but I think I know what's wrong, I am using another query to output the tool_nr, but I need this query to do that :) So maybe it will start working with using left join after I make the changes I need..

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
SELECT t.tool_nr, p.something 
FROM Product p 
JOIN Tools t ON p.tool_id=t.id;
```

Comment: Thanks, but it didn't work, it gave me all the values in one row, but I want each "something" value on a different row :)

Comment: Which kind of output do you need? As I read your question, you would like something like


`tool_nr     something`
`2902        123456`
`2456        254786`
`2902        258956`
`3245        874455`
`2456        987445`

Comment: Yea I do need that and I got it, it was my fault that it didn't work, because I was using another sql query that was useless. Thanks for your help, I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT 
                             t.tool_nr, 
                             p.something 
                       FROM tools t 
                       LEFT JOIN products p 
                       ON p.tool_id = t.id");
```

Comment: I don't get what's the problem, but it just echoes "something" values in one row.. I would like them to be on different rows, but I appreciate the help.

Comment: what do you mean? 2 `something` rows?

Comment: I used something just as a value what I need to get from database :) I needed the values to be on different rows, but I got it, it was my fault that it was not working at first, so thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

From what I gather you want to have the same order of elements as it is for products.
You could try this command:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT Tools.tool_nr, p.something FROM Product  "
                       ." INNER JOIN Tools"
                       ." ON Product.tool_id = Tools.id"
                       ." ORDER BY Product.id");
```

It would give you all rows where a tool exists for a given product. If you want to show all products instead and only show the tools where they exist for the appropriate products:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT Tools.tool_nr, p.something FROM Product  "
                       ." LEFT JOIN Tools"
                       ." ON Product.tool_id = Tools.id"
                       ." ORDER BY Product.id");
```

If instead you want to show all Tools and only those products that exist for these tools:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT Tools.tool_nr, p.something FROM Tools  "
                       ." LEFT JOIN Product"
                       ." ON Product.tool_id = Tools.id"
                       ." ORDER BY Product.id");
```